# How to load an onScroll background image before user scrolls to them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm changing background of a div when the user scrolls to the end of that div. Since its a fixed background, I am not using **HTML** `<img>` tag, instead I am using the **CSS** `background-image:`. With the following `JavaScript` function, it successfully changes the background when i need it, and reverts back when user scrolls back to top.

```js
function transimg(divid,imgurl1,imgurl2) {  
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();       
    var dist = $(divid).offset().top - 50;

    if(st > dist) {
      $(divid).css("background-image", "url(" + imgurl1 +")");  
    }
    else{
      $(divid).css("background-image", "url(" + imgurl2 +")");
    }
  }); 
}
```

## My Question is:

Obviously this loads the image when user scrolls to that offset. Which makes it slow when i host the site and a user has slow connection. So i need the 2nd image to be loaded when the page starts loading. Kind of the opposite of Lazy Load. How can i achieve this ?

I really don't want to use any plugins.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load them in the before body is load. (Add the script at the end of your `body`).

Explanation: When you create an `Image` and set is the `src` property the image file download to your browser.

```js
var images = ['img1', 'img2'];
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = images[i];
}
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for.. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

you could add 2 `background-images` to the `divid` and so they are both loaded at page refresh and then with your JQ toggle between `background-images` depending on scroll.

see snippet below. let me know if it helps ( i check in Network and both images are loaded when page refresh )

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();       
    var dist = $("#container").offset().top - 50;

        if(st > dist) {
            $("#container").css("background-image", "url(" + "http://i.imgur.com/AsqlqnG.jpg" +")");  
            }
        else{
            $("#container").css("background-image", "url(" + "http://i.imgur.com/I8170KA.jpg" +")");
            }
    });
```

```css
#container {
  background-image : url("http://i.imgur.com/I8170KA.jpg"),url("http://i.imgur.com/AsqlqnG.jpg");
  background-size:contain; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:800px;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:50px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="container">

</div>
```